# Como consigo chamar uma função de consulta SQL no Python?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Olá, estou criando uma aplicação para estudos e surgiu uma dúvida. Ela está dividida em 3 arquivos, um main, um database e outro do app. No main eu coloquei o menu principal para que o usuário escolha a opção. No database eu fiz um connect e funções de consulta SQL. No app, está a lógica em si e é aqui eu está a maior dúvida.

Esse é meu arquivo de banco de dados.

```
import sqlite3
class WorkDB:
    def __init__ (self, arquivo):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect('workdb.db')
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    
    def select(self):
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM employee')
        for line in self.cursor.fetchall():
            print(line)
    
    def insert(self, name_emp, age, document, job_title, salary):
        data = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO employee (name_emp, age, document, job_title, salary) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
        self.cursor.execute(data, (name_emp, age, document, job_title, salary))
        self.connection.commit()
    def edit(self, job_title, salary, name_emp):
        data = 'UPDATE OR IGNORE employee SET job_title=?, salary=? WHERE name_emp=?'
        self.cursor.execute(data, (job_title, salary, name_emp))
        self.connection.commit()
    def delete(self, name_emp):
        data = 'DELETE FROM employee WHERE name_emp=?'
        self.cursor.execute(data, (name_emp))
        self.connection.commit()
    
    def end(self):
        self.cursor.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    table_employee = WorkDB('workdb.db')
```

Código do App

```
import database
def listar():
    print(database.table_employee.select()
```

Desculpem, não sai daqui, rs, tentei várias maneiras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, você precisa instanciar a classe no seu arquivo de lógica, e não no seu módulo.
Faça assim:

```
from database import WorkDB


wdb = WorkDB('workdb.db')
wdb.select()
```

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo, funcionou com o select. Agora to quebrando a cabeça com o insert, para tentar inserir um novo funcionario por exemplo.

Comment: Compartilha aí o que tu tá fazendo, e se tá retornando algum erro.

Comment: Basicamente o que quero é fazer um CRUD, porém em arquivos separados, um com um painel principal perguntando qual ação desejada, cadastrar, editar, excluir e consultar. O segundo com a lógica das consultas no sqlite e o terceiro com a lógica do recebimento do usuário pelo painel principal. Eu já reescrevi meu código várias vezes, rs. mas estou com dificuldades de referenciar um ou outro.